# Hilt Inject ActivityComponent dependency into ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm newbie with Hilt and have basic question.

Input data:
I have an AppNavigator that used NavController under the hood

```
class AppNavigatorImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val activity: FragmentActivity
) : AppNavigator {

    private val navController: NavController by lazy {
        val navigationFragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_navigation_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navigationFragment.navController
    }

    override fun navigate(payload: NavigationPayload) {
        when (payload) {
            is NavigationPayload.DeepLink -> {
                navController.navigate(payload.link.toUri())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created ActivityComponent NavigationModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class NavigationModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindAppNavigator(impl: AppNavigatorImpl): AppNavigator

}
```

And I want to make this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class LocationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appNavigator: AppNavigator
) : ViewModel() {

    fun navigateToPurchase() {
        appNavigator.navigate(NavigationPayload.DeepLink("some_deep_link"))
    }
}
```

I got a compilation error:

**[Dagger/MissingBinding] com.wul.carassistant.domain_common.navigation.AppNavigator cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.**

As I understand it's happens because this AppNavigator dependency is ActivityComponent but not ViewModelComponent.

Is there any way to make this AppNavigator injected to ViewModel in a *"pretty way"*?

Comment: `ViewModel` only link to View via `LiveData`, because when the View is recreated, `ViewModel` is still holding your data, and also your View if you hold it => Memory leak happens

Comment: Hello, currently I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a function that will provide your `FragmentActivity`. Are you sure you wan to add activity as dependency to your classes?

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class MyFragmentActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideFragmentActivity(@ActivityContext activity: Context) : FragmentActivity{
    return activity as FragmentActivity
 } 

}
```